# Could iOS social api be used to authenticate people (to let people login to your app) using facebook or twitter?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, twitter

**Clarification** If you want to use ONLY the iOS provided social API (the accounts framework) can you let users login to your app, with their facebook or twitter accounts?
If yes, then what do you use along with the userid (or name, twittername, facebook name) to make sure (on the server side) they are who they are.

**More expressive explanation**
I am having a hard time understanding the workflow/logic behind 3rd party registration and login integration in a native iOS (or Android) app, 
So in iOS there is a central store that keeps users twitter (or facebook) credentials and an app can call the api to get users twitter id, so far so good, but if I want to talk to a backend server and prove that a user is who they claim to be just having the user id is not enough,
Am I missing something?

**My question is** how do you authenticate a user with your backend server if they are not proving you credentials?

Comment: Maybe using Oauth (2) ?!

Comment: @Till does iOS provide oAuth api? or you are saying you can't authenticate users with iOS provided api, you need to use oAuth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can authenticate using ACAccountStore.  Thanks to http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/eric-stroh/ios-6-tutorial-integrating-facebook-your-applications for most of the code below.

```
self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
NSString *key = @"987654"; //put your own key from FB here
NSDictionary *dictFB = //use the ACAccountStore ACFacebookPermissionsKey to help create your dictionary of permsission you'd like to request, such as the users email, writing on the wall, etc.
[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion: ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
    if (granted) {
        NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];
        //it will always be the last object with SSO
        self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
    } else {
        //Fail gracefully...
        NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);
    } 
}];
```

At that point, you have access to an oauth token in the accountStore that you can send to your server for whatever server side interaction you want with facebook.